# How "chrome://inspect#pages" can know other pages that are opened?

Tags: javascript

If you go to "chrome://inspect#pages" you can see other pages url that are opened.
How is this possible?
Is it because of "chrome" protocol?
or
Is it because of "javascript"

or any thing else?

Comment: It's because the program that's presenting information when you enter the 'url' is the same program that opened them.. Put another way, you're tickling Chrome in just the right way to make it enter its "display all opened pages" sub-routine. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is possible: the `chrome:` URL scheme.

`chrome:` is the Google Chrome Meta scheme, so `chrome://inspect#pages` triggers (what should be) an internal call to list those pages.